# Top-tier motherboard that works with Ubuntu out of the box

Tags: motherboard, ubuntu

I am looking into for a top-tier motherboard that is supported out-of-the-box by Ubuntu.

In order to give more context, I am building my own machine. I am choosing the 12900k processor. I will install Ubuntu on the machine, and plan to use overclocking to increase the computational power, hoping to gain extra speed so that my PC can comfortably handle lengthy multiple background jobs (e.g. building indexes ...), and still remain highly responsive for me as a user. Hence, I can see some value form milking the last bit of juice from the unlocked CPU (i.e. overlocking).

It seems that MSI PRO Z690-A WI-FI works out out of the box with Ubuntu 22.04 as mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/a/1389944/1239676. However, I am thinking of a more upscale motherboard that allows for better leverage of CPU overclocking.

Hence, here is what we are looking in the motherboard:

Works out of the box with Ubuntu: There is very minimal pain when installing Ubuntu (or no pain at all). By pain I mean, things such as missing drivers, not properly functioning hardware, and the need to spend hours and hours of doing/searching for fixes. (I had a very bad experience installing Ubuntu on HP Omen, which never succeeded by the way).
Top-tier motherboard: I mean something like, MSI MEG/MPG line of motherboards (for example: MSI MPG Z690 Carbon WiFi), or a ASUS ROG Strix line (for example: ASUS ROG Strix Z690-E).
Handles moderate to extreme overclocking over long periods.
Finally, I would like a recommendation for such a motherboard!

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty much everything on motherboards these days has basic Plug & Play support (as in it supports a universal interface that the OS knows how to use) and Intel gets the CPU & Chipset support out very early (before the products are even released). The problems with compatibility will be limited to specific devices, like an ethernet or WiFi device. Again, products from Intel are very good on the Linux support side so keep an eye open for motherboards that have Intel brand ethernet/WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

For Overclocking, you are dependant on 3 things, power, cooling and sillicon lottery. Only the first one is motherboard dependant, so I will reccomend a mobo that has good power delivery. Also for Linux support, all motherboards I have used (and those are a lot) run Linux without modding any settings. With some mobos though, you need to turn Secure boot off, but I can't see from specs it it's needed

For mobo, you can get the ASUS ROG Strix Z690-E GAMING WIFI, although it's pretty expensive and Wifi support on Linux is gonna be hit or miss (if you miss but you do have an internet cable, you can AskUbuntu for help). The VRM specs look promising, so you should have the power delivery to overclock. (and according to Tweakers user Rooieduvel the VRM's are also decently cooled)